# how to install rubygems?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, homebrew

I'm having some serious issues with Ruby, Gems, RVM, everything. I'm trying to install lolcommits just to have some fun with git commits. If I run:

```
gem install lolcommits
```

It sends back a message saying:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8 directory.
```

Which, of course, I have no idea what that means. From what I've gathered, my Ruby should be installed in `usr/local/bin` rather than going to `/Library/Ruby/Gems/`. How can I fix this?

I think I turned my PATH into a mess, it looks like:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/jmakaila/.rvm/bin
```

and my `GEM_PATHS:` are:

```
GEM PATHS: 
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
/Users/jmakaila/.gem/ruby/1.8
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
```

Comment: Are you actually using RVM or Homebrew here? Your question has nothing about them and you're using the system Ruby.

Comment: rvm is installed if that's what you mean

Comment: @AndrewMarshall The question *is* tagged `rvm`...

Comment: @alestanis But it's also tagged Homebrew. That's two ways to install Ruby, neither of which the OP's GEM_PATH indicates they're actually using.

Comment: I tagged it as homebrew because lolcommits uses homebrew to install dependencies. I used rvm to install a new version of ruby and it appears to have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `rvm install 1.9.2` and then ran `gem install lolcommits` and it seemed to have worked fine. Ran a disk/permissions verification to attempt to repair my `chmod` mistakes.

Comment: In your OP, the error is caused because you were trying to install gems using the built-in MacOS Ruby.  
By doing the rvm install, it looks like you fixed your ruby path and generated the local gem installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing your gem with admin rights using `sudo`:

```
sudo gem install xxxxx
```

Comment: i've read in like, 8000 different questions on this site that using sudo to install gems is not recommended

Comment: You can try changing the rights on `/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8` then

Comment: It looks like you're on a Mac. Macs are very... conservative ;)

Comment: No! Do **not** change the permissions of the system Ruby. Use `sudo` or install Ruby a different way.

Comment: ...how do i revert this? it didn't seem to do anything but I don't want my system permissions messed up.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall Do you know why on Macs sometimes you need to use `sudo` and sometimes you don't? You should post that as an answer. We might both learn something (the OP and me I mean)

Comment: i verified my permissions and hopefully fixed that ish, did a `rvm install 1.9.2` and then another `gem install lolcommits` and it seems to have gone through and installed fine...

Comment: Don't mess with using `sudo` because that version of Ruby was installed by Apple for their use, and there are Apple-installed apps that expect it. You can run Ruby apps, but they expect certain things to be there, and updates to the system could expect certain revisions and fail if they don't find them. It's safer and smarter to use RVM or rbenv or one of the other packaging systems to install a new/unique/separate version of Ruby for your own use some where else. I favor rbenv right now, but YMMV.

Comment: "how do i revert this? it didn't seem to do anything but I don't want my system permissions messed up." Use Disk Utility to repair the permissions of your boot disk. It will reset them to what they should be.